# What would a specialist be called whose job is to convince people?

Tags: single-word-requests

This person would be called upon when, say, a potential partner or client is still doubtful and having a difficult time making a decision. The specialist is paid to find just the right words, arguments, and tone, and has enough natural charm, to persuade them.

The word *persuader* has a number of meanings and tons of ambiguous connotations.

Comment: Do such people even exist? I am not aware of their existence outside of political lobbying and organized crime.

Comment: A persuader, being a large wooden mallet, can still be considered appropriate.

Comment: This seems to call for the answer "liar".

Comment: @Joshua: Lying may, but does not have to be, part of that person's skill set.

Comment: @Ricky It certainly doesn't have to be part of that person's skillset, but (in my experience at least) it takes many of the same skills as successfully lying -- keeping your story consistent, embedding easily verifiable grains of truth among harder-to-verify parts, not coming across as dishonest... Of course, "liar" is still the wrong word for that, as "liar" doesn't imply any amount of skill in lying.

Comment: Without thinking too deep about it in terms of "*a specialist whose job is to convince people*", that would be a defense "attorney" or even a "prosecutor" to convince the jury or a judge perhaps. Then you have a "recruiter" such as a military recruiter to convince people to join the military or an employment recruiter trying to convince you that a prospect job opening may be more beneficial to you than your current employer. In terms of convincing potential partners or clients, I'm not certain those fit the bill though but generically perhaps.

Comment: Note that "closer" is a casual term, it wouldn't be an official job title.  (the officla title might just be "Sales Manager", "Lawyer", or indeed sometimes "Negotiator."

Comment: Many of the answers are completely off the mark.

Comment: @Lambie: And three close votes to boot.

Comment: The first thing I get to think about is "salesman".

Answer (score 50):

In the situation you are describing, the person is called a Closer.

From Dictionary.com a [closer](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/closer) is:

> a  person  or  thing   that  closes

Which isn't terribly helpful at all, until we look for the correct disambiguation of Close:

> to  arrange   the   final   details  of; to  conclude   negotiations   about

and

> to  complete  or  settle  (a  contract  or  transaction);   consummate:

These definitions are probably the best fit for the term "Close" in the context provided.

Could also be a [lobbyist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lobbyist?s=t), or if talking about a group of lobbyists just a lobby.
Also from Dictionary.com:

> a  person   who   tries  to  influence   legislation  on  behalf  of a  special   interest;  a  member  of a lobby

Answer (score 34):

Especially in business, this person is often called a *closer*.

> [Closer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/closer): A person who is skilled at bringing a business transaction to
>   a satisfactory conclusion.

*Example: Harvey Specter in the TV series **Suits** is called the best closer in New York because of his ability to come to agreements with his clients.*

Comment: With his clients, or with the clients of opposing counsel? He doesn't like to go to court; I had taken "closer" here to mean he always settles, and does so in ways favourable for his client.

Comment: @MathieuK. He's called a closer because he closes cases. Who's on the other end of the deal ranges from his clients, his client's opponents or opposing attorneys.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest **[negotiator](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negotiator#dataset-cbed)**

> A person who has formal discussions with someone else in order to reach an agreement, or a person whose job is to do this

Answer (score 14):

Not exactly what you are looking for but a closer word is **[Evangelist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evangelist)**, meaning *a zealous advocate of something.*

It was earlier associated with people who seek others to convert to Christianity by preaching.

---

Nowadays we have the Technical or Technology Evangelists. From [the page about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist):

> *A technology evangelist is a person who builds a critical mass of support for a given technology and then **establishes it as a technical standard in a market that is subject to network effects**.*

Comment: The primary meaning in my experience is still the conversion to Christianity one.

Comment: @Justin I guess you don't work in Management Consultancy. Plenty of evangelists, but not much Christian ethics!

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the new definition, just saying the earlier definition is certainly not obsolete (at least not in predominantly Protestant parts of the US).

Comment: I'm seeing this a lot lately. I don't really like the usage, but can't dispute it's common! In the mainstream language world though it definitely is still associated with religion.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on the context of the situation.

**Negotiator** is probably the closest general word in common usage for what you are describing. That, however, carries implications that the final result will be some sort of deal and that there may be some give and take. That would not be the ideal word without those connotations.

You have essentially provided the job description for a **Lawyer**, but that word implies there will be some interaction with legal institutions or other lawyers. It may also imply that the person being referenced has a license, depending on the jurisdiction being discussed.

A **Lobbyist** will perform those functions, but that term is almost exclusively used in connection with politicians or similar bureaucracies.

A **Consultant** may play a similar role. Normally, a consultant will be brought in to help determine the best course of action rather than to persuade a person that a previously chosen course was correct. However, the end result may be the same.

Another answer suggested **Influencer**. I agree with this, but influencer is a relatively informal term and also one that carries connotations of influencing large groups of people. I have never yet heard of an influencer being brought in to target a specific individual.

**Closer** was also suggested. Again, I agree but this is also a fairly informal term that carries some significant connotations. In the contexts I am familiar with, Closers are usually involved in sealing a deal and the word would sound odd used in a context that was not expected to end with a contract or transaction.

**Rhetor** or (with credit to Ooker) **rhetorician** also come close in their literal meanings. The words refer to someone who is an expert in rhetoric which is essentially the art of persuasion. However, those words are not in common usage and many native English speakers may be unfamiliar with them. They now mostly comes up in discussing historical teachers of rhetoric which was common in some time periods of Ancient Greece and Ancient Rome.

(With Credit to Brian Drummond) **Evangelist** has a similar meaning. Originally, it was used almost exclusively in religious contexts, but the meaning has been broadening. It comes up often in technology now. However, like influencer and some of the others, evangelism is more often associated with trying to sway large numbers of people rather than trying to persuade a specific individual.

**Advocate** refers to someone who presses a specific position and comes very close to your description. However, advocate is sometimes used a synonym for lawyer (along with many others including counselor, attorney, barrister, etc.) When it is not being used in the sense of being a synonym for attorney it does not necessarily carry an implication of skill or training the way that negotiator, lobbyist, and consultant do.

Comment: Perhaps it's more common to use **rhetorician** than **rhetor**. The academic field **rhetorics** usually goes along with composition (writing) to become **rhetorics and composition**. Freshmen in colleges are usually taught this to construct concrete arguments.

Comment: +1. The only answer to explore context. Good list of words but missing "evangelist" where the context is religious (or the passions involved are similar), "zealot" (similar) and "advocate" (originally legal, but now more widely used.

Comment: @Ooker I might have to look into that when I have time. Rhetor is the word I have seen in discussions of history. Sophist also had a related meaning. I have not seen rhetorician before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Good point, regarding evangelist and advocate. I think zealot refers more to someone who passionately believes in something and doesn't necessarily imply advocating for it. In fact, I've seen zealot used more often in connection with violence than speech. Thanks.

Comment: Lawyers iron-out deals; others make them.

Comment: @Lambie While that is true in some cases, it is far from universally true. Lawyers often serve as negotiators to make the deal.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer (as the best) if you provided some degree of supporting evidence, as is normally required for this kind of answer. At the very least, link each word to a dictionary definition. As it stands, there's no way for the EL&U community to know whether it's *authoritative* or just a comprehensively stated personal opinion. For further guidance, see [answer].

Answer (score 11):

**[influencer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/influencer)** *noun*

> [​MARKETING] a person or group that has the ability to influence the behaviour or opinions of others:
>   *The influencer is the individual whose effect on the purchase decision is in some way significant or authoritative.*

*See also:*

> Individuals who have the power to affect purchase decisions of others because of their (real or perceived) authority, knowledge, position, or relationship. In consumer spending, members of a peer group or reference group act as influencers. **In business to business (organizational) buying**, internal employees (engineers, managers, purchasers) or **external consultants act as influencers.**
>   ([BusinessDictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/influencers.html))

Comment: *Convincer*! Is it not possible?

Comment: @mahmudkoya It is not so specific and not widely used today in this sense. It is true that *convincer* is a word and some marketing literature did use the term, though, e.g., Dorothy Leeds, *Smart Questions: The Essential Strategy for Successful Managers*, 2000, pp.63-64.

Comment: Interestingly, Dr. Larry Iverson seems to believe that the only person who can convince you is yourself (*The Secret to Persuasiveness*, 2011.) and uses *influence* instead of *convince*.

Comment: *Influencer* is someone who is already in position to influence others. I am not aware of a mechanism by which you can hire a freelance "influencer" to come in and persuade someone in your organization (other than a mob persuader).

Comment: @michael.hor257k "I am not aware of a mechanism by which you can hire a freelance "influencer" ..." -- Please see BusinessDictionary (link provided above) and Google for the word along with *marketing*. Good Luck.

Comment: I am talking about real life.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Things happen in real life that one may not be aware of. "Could happen" isn't the same as "can never happen."

Answer (score 6):

In politics, that would be a **lobbyist**.

From the [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobbyist),

> Lobbying, persuasion, or interest representation is the act of
>   attempting to influence the actions, policies, or decisions of
>   officials in their daily life, most often legislators or members of
>   regulatory agencies.

His (or her) job is specifically as you describe, with politicians as the intended target.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. However, you could improve this answer with a definition and/or example of use.  You can also use "Lobbyist" outside a political context, but admittedly that's more rare.

Comment: @BruceWayne - How's that?

Comment: +1 That should really be the perfect answer, except that the word is used more in the political context than in commercial parlance, as BruceWayne already noted.

Answer (score 5):

Almost all the suggested answers relate to business deals: a dealmaker, a negotiator, a closer (this last carrying the implication of *closing the deal*). Doesn't strike me as answering the question that was actually asked.

In the UK, a specialist who is hired to convince *people* (really, I ought to say *the people*), who might once have been called a politician, is these days more commonly known as a **spin doctor**.

When your job is *to convince*, you are talking about selling an idea, in the way that an ad man might try to sell a new product. Convincing people of something is very, very different from *closing* the deal. It is about convincing people to *want* to buy (something), not about negotiating the *terms* of the deal, and definitely *not* merely about getting the buyer's signature to close the deal.

In the advertising business, the ad agency's job used to be to convince the public to want to buy their client's  product. In politics, the politician's job used to be to convince the public to want to "buy" their party's policies. Selling the people on the product - that was the concept.

So an ad agency's executive was called an **ad man**, but the more modern term, usual in politics in England, was **spin-doctor**, the man who puts a *positive spin* on all political news: i.e. construes everything in the best possible light.

His job is to convince people that the party is doing a good job, and thereby to convince them of the soundness of its policies, and hence to convince them to vote for it.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a job, that would be a "spokesperson". They do it on behalf of someone else.

If it is a self-motivated activity it would be an "advocate".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is the start of good answer. Ideally you should use dictionary definitions and add some reasoning as to why these answers are correct.

Comment: "advocate must be a strong contender. The word comes from a legal background but is more widely used where persuasion has to be thorough, generally logical and fact based rather than emotional.

For an interesting use in a religious context, see "devil's advocate", whose role is to persuade holy men that another holy person was evil, and therefore should not be elevated to sainthood.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like shouting my answer... I wonder why?

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dealmaker):

> ## dealmaker *noun*
>
> deal·mak·er | \ˈdēl-ˌmā-kər  \
> *plural* **dealmakers**
> Definition of *dealmaker*
> : **someone who is given to or skilled in negotiating deals or agreements : one who makes deals**
>
> > Her reputation as a hard-driving *dealmaker* was known to heads of state and corporate CEOs all over the world.
> > — Johnnie L. Roberts et al.
> > He's a *dealmaker*, a power broker, a convener of interests—in short, the living definition of the career politician …
> > — Douglas Foster

Comment: Most famous one probably being Monty Hall.  Google it if you don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Since ages, ***middlemen*** have been doing this and sometimes they are the ones making the most in the deal.

ODO:

> **[middleman](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/middleman)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** A person who arranges business or political deals between other people.
>
> ‘In that role he was the key middleman responsible for arranging the
>   £40 billion deal in 1986.’
>
> ‘There are now technological middlemen who mediate how we even see
>   each other.’

Comment: For ages, since the Middle Ages

Answer (score 2):

The obvious avocation is *public relations* (**PR**).  The trouble, of course, lies in the word *public*.  Only the very wealthy individuals can afford such specialists.

When it comes to private or personal disputes, there is the role of ‘*mediator*’.  These can even have a formal role in disputes over separation and divorce.  But the role of the mediator is one of neutrality between two parties, rather than partisan support or advocacy for one individual.

There is an art of persuasion.  It is called ‘*rhetoric*’.  In Western history, this art of persuasion back to the 5th century BCE, when travelling experts in the art of persuasion offered to teach the art of persuasion.

It came to prominence in Athens, where the radical democracy (of law courts as well as political assembly) left the well born and affluent without any source of power other than popular assent.

This seems to have contributed to the popularity of a number of philosophers/teachers, claiming, among other things, to teach the art of persuasion, which for some amounted to convincing people to see proposed actions to be in their own interest.  They came to be known as ‘sophists’, from which we derive the pejorative word *sophistry*, or the use of crafty arguments to manoeuvre people into agreeing to what we want.

I very much fear that any word that becomes associated with successful persuasion, however sweet, will sooner or later be tarred with a similar brush.

Comment: Hi Tuffy. I'd upvote your answer, except it lacks authoritative evidence such as a dictionary definition for *public relations* (e.g. to clarify whether "person" is a necessary component of the term). Without this, your answer is merely a comprehensively stated personal opinion.

Comment: @Chappo You’re quite right.

Comment: public relations has zero to do with making a deal.  A mediator is a person who settles disputes between parties.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the position to have a bit more sinister feel to it, I would go with 'fixer' or 'mechanic', implying a bit of hit-man action, like "an offer you can't refuse".

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives with a more negative connotation: if he’s paid to say things that aren’t true, he’s a **bullshitter** or **bullshit artist**.  (This might be Bowdlerized to **BSer** or **BS artist**.)  If he’s a true believer in a cause and promotes it no matter what, he’s an **advocate** or **activist**.  If they’re annoying about it, **fanatic**.  If he’s doing it for a political party, he’s a **spin artist** or perhaps **spinmeister**.  **Apologist** originally meant a type of religious evangelists who studied other religious traditions, but has come to mean defending the indefensible.  A disparaging slang term for someone paid to defend anything their employer does is a **flack** or **PR flack**.  Someone who writes advertisements (especially if they’re insincere, poorly-argued or unoriginal) is a **hack**.  A lawyer who’ll say anything to win a case is a **shyster**.

Comment: "Whitehouse Spokesperson" if doing it to convince people that everything the President says or tweets is not malarkey, but in fact, everything the President says or tweets is tremendously wise, obvious, and great.

Comment: @geneSummons That works, but with slightly different shades of meaning. Spokespeople literally speak for their employers, saying whatever they are told to say. They aren’t expected necessarily to agree with it themselves, although old-fashioned people like me might say that if they have a strong moral objection to something they’re told to say, they should resign. The person at the White House who’s supposed to take questions from the press and explain the Administration’s position as well as they possibly can has the job title White House Press Secretary.

Comment: @geneSummons Anpther word often used for people who might or might not be formally employed as spokespeople, but who are so close to a candidate that they are assumed to speak for them, is **surrogate**. Cable networks in the US now call the partisan talking-heads who argue with each other on TV **strategists**.

Comment: Since when has the word bullshitter meant specifically a person who makes deals??

Comment: @Lambie You call bullahit? But seriously, yes, that's a broader term. It could be appropriate if he sees himself as trying to trick or deceive the target.

Comment: A _hack_ is, or was in my youth, an abusive term for a yellow-sheet journalist (as a certain category of newspapers was known way-back-when), not specifically a term for an ad-man. In fact I don't recall the term ever being used in connection with advertising: the definition offered is exactly right, but it referred to a certain type of newsmen, not to ad-men.

Comment: No one (outside of a lunatic asylum) would advertise a job with the job description "wanted: a _bullshitter_". No specialist would be called by such a description. And it really is a description of the job, not a job title. But I feel a job title was what the o/p was asking for.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with closing a business deal or reeling in a doubtful customer but I think you're looking for The Mentalist, from the show... The Mentalist.

In the show, and in real life, mentalists can perform extraordinary feats of mind. They're not actually doing magic or even performing magic tricks though, so they don't necessarily need tools. You can think of a kind of Sherlock Holmes but also with excellent social and people manipulation skills.

Mentalist has many meanings in the dictionaries I've looked at but I think this quote from yourdictionary.com summarizes the dictionary meaning pretty well:

> mentalist is a mind reader or magic person who can perform extraordinary tricks that rely on mental powers.

But wait! This part from wikipedia.com is actually, in my opinion, a much better explanation:

> Mentalists generally do not mix "standard" magic tricks with their
>   mental feats. Doing so associates mentalism too closely with the
>   theatrical trickery employed by stage magicians. Many mentalists claim
>   not to be magicians at all, arguing that it is a different art form
>   altogether. The argument is that mentalism invokes belief and when
>   presented properly, is offered as being "real" be it a claim of
>   psychic ability, or proof that supports other claims such as a
>   photographic memory, being a "human calculator", the power of
>   suggestion, NLP, etc. Mentalism plays on the senses
>   and a spectator's perception of tricks.

I understand this is an out of the box idea but I really like this word instead of the other suggestions like "influencer" or "closer", so I just wanted to bring this one to attention.

Comment: I believe the word you're thinking of is _mesmerism_, actually: the ability to convince an audience of something through the use of hypnosis or mind control.

Comment: @Ed999 That is an entirely different word and the manners used are also entirely different.

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple

```
salesperson
```

A salesperson does not need to have detailed information on what they are trying to "sell" or "convince".  As the sayings go, "a good salesman can sell ice cubes to an Eskimo"

A good salesperson doesn't sell the product they sell the person.  They find common ground, find what their target cares about and then they work it until they get it.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to the site. I don't think a *lobbyist* would normally be called a salesperson, except as an insult. In any case, your answer is *too* "simple": the system has flagged it for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - e.g. adding a dictionary definition. For further guidance, see [answer]. Make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: +1. You are completely right @MichaelFever. Only sane answer in this thread. :)

Comment: +1 What else does a salesman/salesperson do other than try to 'sell' something to someone by convincing them to 'buy' or agree to it. I can't understand why this hasn't had more votes, and I certainly don't agree with @Chappo. Brevity can be a virtue.

Comment: @Bobble on ELU brevity is **not** a virtue, which is why this answer (along with our comments) will soon be deleted if it remains unedited. I recommend you read the guidance in the Help Centre to get a better understanding of how SE works.

Comment: @Chappo By definition, a lobbyist is "a person who takes part in an organized attempt to influence legislators (government).  That is a very narrowly defined role where the question was "What would a specialist be called whose job is to convince people?"  Now let's do a reversal test.  Could a salesperson be considered a lobbyist?  No of course not.  But could a lobbyist be considered a salesperson?  Absolutely they can. Examine the roles.  Both are acting out of financial gain, not out of a personal reason.  They are both doing a job. Lobbyist does not work for this answer, salesperson does.

Comment: @Chappo furthermore, the top voted answer here is "closer".  A "closer" is a senior salesperson!   https://grantcardone.com/5-techniques-to-become-a-master-closer/

Comment: Is a salesperson a "*specialist*" - I think not. A diplomat whose expertise is closing intergovernmental deals is definitely a closer, but they're not a salesperson (except purely metaphorically). In any case, it would seem the majority of EL&U voters on this answer share my view - your answer is neither *authoritative*, (you've provided no independent evidence to support it) nor correct. However, with -3 votes, you can [earn a badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/peer-pressure) if you delete your answer. You'll be in good company: some high-rep users are in that badge list!

Comment: Only -2 now, I'm getting some support lol.  Fundamentally the question is flawed and vague.  The original question didn't say anything about lobbyists and now closers who specialize in "closing intergovernmental deals".  I think I'll stick to StackOverflow where the questions & answers are not open to interpretation at all.

Comment: Nope, a diplomat whose expertise is closing intergovernmental deals is definitely a diplomat.